# Predicting word vectors instead of words (Natural Language Processing)

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, vectorization, word-embedding, encoder-decoder

I wonder whether there are any attempts to predict *word embedding vectors* as targets in neural networks architectures (like Transformers, Sequence-to-Sequence-Models or simple RNNs) using for example *mean squared errors* as a loss-function instead of predicting words as categories with *softmax*. Couldn’t find any articles on that topic. Does someone know any papers on that or if not a reason why that‘s not being done?

***For clarification***:

Take for example a simple Encoder-Decoder-Architecture as proposed by Cho et al. 2014 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1078). In such models (where sequences of words a produced), a softmax activation function is commonly used in the output layer in order to predict target words. If you have 30,000 words in your vocabulary, you need 30,000 neurons in the output layer.

*My question is now*: Instead of predicting words in the output layer, why not represent target words as vectors? Practically this should be easy to accomplish when using pretrained vector representations like *fastText* or *vec2words*. Such vectors spaces describe a word using for example 300 float values. One could first look up every target word in the vector space and then use the floats describing the word instead of the word itself (as a category) as a target. The model will then predict the float values of the vector representation. When using such a model to predict a word (or a sequence of words), we would simply use the predicted values to look up the closest word in the vector space.

The *advantage* of this procedure should be twofold. *First*, it would significantly reduce the number of neurons in the output layer (from 30,000 to 300). *Second*, training such a model would – from a theoretical point of view – lead to a better underlying „language understanding“ of the model since the vector representations are semantically and grammatically rich while the words are just monolytic categories.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is in essence a Siamese network, where a result is an embedding and the loss is based on similarity between examples.

The network does use slightly more complicated loss function called triplet loss, which is based on maximising distance between different examples and minimizing it with similar ones.

I recommend reading [this link](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/chopra-05.pdf) or in fact any others on the topic of Siamese Networks.

Comment: Thank you - that‘s in fact interesting. However, that's going in a different direction. What I meant is rather: when for example using word vectors like word2vec or fastText, the dimensions of the target-words are in fact known. So why not use an output-layer with say 300 units and predict the vector-representation of that word instead of the word as a category?

Comment: Sure, that could be done. Word2vec in fact kind of resembles a structure of a neural network and for sure can be adapted to act in a simillar way.

You can predict vector representation by (for example) making the last linear layer have, say, 200 neurons. The issue however is finding an appropriate loss function, as we don't really have "targets" in a problem that You described. Instead, something from the realm of siamese networks (like triplet loss) has to be used to compute loss